# $(this).checked not picking up checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is not picking up checkboxes correctly (if checked)
with this function:

```
function playerJson() {
    players = [];
    $('input[name=playerCheckList]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).checked) {
            players.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    return $.toJSON(players);
}
```

I use this function to check all buttons (correctly)

```
 $(function () {
    $("#checkAllPlayers").click(function () {
        $('input[name=playerCheckList]').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
    });
});
```

If I don't have the if statement:

```
if ($(this).checked)
```

from the first piece of code, it correctly picks up all the values (checked or not)

So, this statement is probably the problem, but I'm not sure why.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the other answers say, `.checked` will not work on a jQuery object.

This is easier visualized this way:

`$(this).checked` returns undefined/error because it is a jQuery object, not an element.
`$(this)[0].checked` returns the value of `checked` because you are referencing the element itself, not the jQuery object referencing the element.

Below is a modified and fixed version of your script, eliminating the use of jQuery entirely for `checked` and for `value` as they are a pointless use of jQuery. The other use makes a little more sense, and so it will remain in my answer.

```
function playerJson() {
        players = [];
        $('input[name=playerCheckList]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                players.push(this.value);
            }
        });
        return $.toJSON(players);
    }
```

Comment: _"$(this0[0].checked returns the value of checked"_, no it throws an error (_not the downvoter_.)

Answer (score 15):

That is referring to a jQuery object, which has no property 'checked' (The DOM would have that property though). You need to get the attribute value.

```
$(this).prop("checked");
```

Edit: I support [qwertynl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123778/1022697) because `vanilla.js`

Comment: or `$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: Just a note: `is()` is slightly slower than `prop()` (`attr()` is the slowest) and are all slower than vanilla. Still, `is()` would work, of course.

Answer (score 9):

`$(this).checked` does not work because `$(this)` is a jQuery oject.

Just look at the `checked` attribute of the DOM object (`this`):

```
...
if (this.checked) {
    players.push(this.value);
}
...
```

Comment: @BlackSheep I used no jQuery :-P